# Referencing the parent of a class method

Tags: python, python-3.x, class

I posted this a while ago. I have been making some progress, and this appears to be trickier than I thought. [Python: Getting the name of a callable function argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48883712/python-getting-the-name-of-a-callable-function-argument)

I have made progress with `@wraps`, and now I am able to get a bit further. This is a separate question that merits its own thread.

Shortly, how can I access somehow the class instance, whose member a function call is?  Here is a complete and working code snippet illustrating the issue (python 3 only).

The reason why I need to do this is explained in my other post if anyone cares. When I call `b.set_something()`, the parameter is a method call to a. But as there is no method "set_something_else" in A but it is grabbed by the `__getattr__()` hack, I am struggling a bit to identify what I am working with, as I need to "explain" over a messaging protocol to the remote server, which class instance executed which functions, with possible callable parameters to other classes.

So I thought to add an id to every class instance and use this as a reference.  When my `b` object receives the call to `b.get_something()` with `a.get_something_else` as an argument, I can now because of @wraps detect in my b that

1. The function is of class A
2. The function name is "get_something_else"

Now the only missing link is to grab the "id" from the *instance* of A, whose member `get_something_else` happens to be. This would allow me to link everything together on the remote side.  But how do I reference it from B? The only information I have is the callable parameter a.get_something_else.  I am able to freely modify classes Foo and Bar but not the final part how variables a and b are constructed.

```
from functools import wraps
import uuid

class Bar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = str(uuid.uuid4())

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        @wraps(name)
        def foo(*args, **kwargs):
            _kwa = {}
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                if callable(v):
                    cn = "{}.{}".format(v.__qualname__.split(".")[0], v.__wrapped__)
                    # How to get "id" from the object whose member v is??
                    _kwa[k] = cn
                    continue
                else:
                    _kwa[k] = v
            x = {"args": args, "kwargs": _kwa}
            print(x)
        return foo

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.id = str(uuid.uuid4())

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        @wraps(name)
        def foo(*args, **kwargs):
            _kwa = {}
            for k, v in kwargs.items():
                if callable(v):
                    cn = "{}.{}".format(v.__qualname__.split(".")[0], v.__wrapped__)
                    _kwa[k] = cn
                    continue
                else:
                    _kwa[k] = v
            x = {"args": args, "kwargs": _kwa}
            print(x)
        return foo

a = Foo()
b = Bar()
b.set_something(command=a.set_something_else)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is exactly what you’d want but have you checked out the super function? 
Class Parent():
       Def **init**(self):
           super(Parent, self).**init**()

Comment: In this case there is no useful parent as A and B are not inheriting from anything.